# text on image html css3

Tags: css, html

I try to put text in image and email that image so I do this

```css
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 150px;
  top: 350px;
}
```

```html
<table width="400" class="main" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="images/bd.jpg" border="0" />
      <p id="text">
        Hello
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I check email .. image is displayed but text is displayed under image . not on image so how I display text on image

Comment: Different email clients handle CSS & html differently. This is too broad of a question

Comment: First of all, You don't open your TR correctly so your table won't work/load properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="400" class="main" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <td>
                <img src="images/bd.jpg" border="0"  />
                <p id="text">
                    Hello
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 


    #text {
            z-index: 100;
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            left: 150px;
            top: 0;
        }
    table{
       position:relative;
    }
```

Comment: Try to explain what you have updated or tried to get this solution instead of just pasting code.

Comment: what is this @Jana

Comment: You should have the parent element as `position:relative`. then only the child elements which has the property `position:absolute` can sit above the `parent element`

Comment: In your case `img` or `table` should have `position:relative`..then `p` can have `position:absolute`

Comment: i tried but still text is displayed below image.. i.stack.imgur.com/FjAUI.png  @Jana

Comment: i placed cid:image .. is this problem ?

Comment: change `top:350px` to `top:0` in `#text` ..i have tested this..working..

Comment: what is `cid:image`?

Answer (score 0):

To display `absolute` positioned element relatively to the parent, not screen, you need to set `position: relative` to the parent (to the `table` in your case). In this example the image is under the text and the text is positioned relatively to the image:

```css
table {
  position: relative;
}

#text {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 150px;
    top: 350px;
}
```

```html
<table width="400" class="main" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Blue_Tiger_Im_IMG_9450.jpg" border="0"  />
      <p id="text">
        Hello
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set `img` has `position: relative;`

```css
img {
  position: relative;
}

#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table width="400" class="main" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/436114/274833056/stock-vector-sample-grunge-retro-red-isolated-ribbon-stamp-sample-stamp-sample-sample-sign-274833056.jpg" border="0" />
      <p id="text">
        Hello
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i tried but still text is displayed below image.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjAUI.png

Comment: i use src="cid:background".. is this problem ?

Comment: What is `cid:background`? `src` must be an URL!

Comment: when i wrote src="images/ab.jpg" then image is not display in email whereas when i use cid:background then image is displayed.. there is code which is already developed in html i am trying to modify this ..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the image the background image of the paragraph but you have to adjust the size as your image to make it visible

```
#text {
    background-image: url("images/bd.jpg");

}
```